# My SQL is have to search for articles in my database within price range of 3,00 and 4,00 but the code does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, between

Cam someone help me....

I have to bookmark my SQL Query, i have to create a code to boormark all products within the tabel "album", and the price must be between 3,00 and 4,00 But it doesnt work. Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Im new in SQL so sorry if its a dumb qeustion xD

Screenshot of the code down here.

https://gyazo.com/c85bfb44ccb326ac2f0c6652391e327e

```
SELECT * FROM `album` WHERE prijs BETWEEN 3,00 and 4,00;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially notice that they recommend not posting screenshots of code. Screenshots are hard to search, they defeat screenreaders used by sight-impaired people, and it makes it hard for anyone to test your code if they want to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asuming prjis is a valid number data type don'use comma for decimal

```
select * from  album where prjis between 3.00 and 4.00;
```